# Random images picked from Array are the same

Tags: javascript, html

So on my page I am displaying 5 random images in a line, when I reload the page the images change, that works. but sometimes 2 of the same images that are picked are the same because I use the same Array for all 5 images, is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

this is the code I have so far:

```js
images = new Array();
    
    images[0] = "<a href ='001.html'><img src='/images/001.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    images[1] = "<a href ='002.html'><img src='/images/002.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    images[2] = "<a href ='003.html'><img src='/images/003.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    images[3] = "<a href ='004.html'><img src='/images/004.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    images[4] = "<a href ='005.html'><img src='/images/005.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    images[5] = "<a href ='006.html'><img src='/images/006.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    images[6] = "<a href ='007.html'><img src='/images/007.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    images[7] = "<a href ='008.html'><img src='/images/008.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    images[8] = "<a href ='009.html'><img src='/images/009.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    images[9] = "<a href ='010.html'><img src='/images/010.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    images[10] = "<a href ='011.html'><img src='/images/011.jpg' width='125' height='125'></a>";
    
    Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)
    document.write(images[Number]);
```

Comment: Don't call your variable `Number`!

Comment: [Obligatory Dilbert reference](http://assets.amuniversal.com/321a39e06d6401301d80001dd8b71c47)

Comment: why not just do a pop from the array using random? then you're assured no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to ensure that you only initialize the array once, and then remove the element you randomly selected so that it can't be selected again, using `images.splice(Number, 1)`.  (But don't name your variable `Number`.)

```
var options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

function selectItem() {
  var n, item;

  if (options.length === 0) { return; }

  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);

  item = options[n];

  options.splice(n, 1);

  return item;
};
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdhowie/vbc8jxqa/) that demonstrates the basic technique.

You could also use a function that encapsulates this logic:

```
function randomItemDispenser(items) {
  return function () {
    var n;

    if (items.length !== 0) {
      n = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);

      return items.splice(n, 1)[0];
    }
  };
}
```

This function accepts an array as an argument and returns a function that, when called, will remove and return a random element from that array, until the array becomes empty:

```
var dispenser = randomItemDispenser(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);
var i;

while ((i = dispenser()) !== undefined) {
    // Do something with i
}
```